# How to safely download and gpg verify a Debian source package?

Tags: apt, software-sources, debian, gnupg

I need specific (source or binary) packages from Debian.

Can I download the package using apt-get?

How can I add the Debian repository to my sources.list so it only gets used on a by case base? Without messing up my system by using the whole Debian repository?

How can I get the gpg key for the Debian repository to be sure the package was signed by the Debian archive?

(Please don't tell me, that the system may break. I am aware of that and couldn't care less, because I can easily restore a VM snapshot.)

Comment: Part of the solution might be the debian-archive-keyring package which includes /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg.

Comment: Another part of the solution might be Apt-Pinning: http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html

Comment: My this answer help you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/263705/is-there-a-way-to-pull-source-for-a-package-for-a-specific-release/263755#263755

Answer (score 15):

There are several questions which I will answer individually:

**How to download (and not install) individual binary package?**

`apt-get` has an option to only download the package:

```
-d  Download only - do NOT install or unpack archives
```

You will find the downloaded package in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.  In this case you will have to add a new sources list configuration to apt.

**How to download individual source package?**

```
apt-get source <package>
```

or when you know the location of the .dsc file:

```
dget http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/k/knot/knot_1.2.0~rc3-1.dsc
```

Both approaches do verify the signature on the files

**How to pin the sources.list aka how do I not mess my installation?**

You have already pointed to the page of basic description for [APT Pinning](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html), and I would only add that you probably want to read the [apt_preferences](http://linux.die.net/man/5/apt_preferences) manpage which also have nice examples to accomplish things you need.  Especially see the section 'Tracking Stable' in EXAMPLES, since it describes something very close to your needs:

There's an usefull command when playing with multiple sources and APT Pinning:

```
# apt-cache policy knot
knot:
  Installed: 1.1.3-1~bpo60+1
  Candidate: 1.2.0~rc3-1~bpo60+1
  Version table:
     1.2.0~rc3-1~bpo60+1 0
        500 http://deb.knot-dns.cz/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.1.3-1~bpo60+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.5-1~bpo60+1 0
        500 http://ppa.sury.org/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
```

This shows that the installed version is 1.1.3-1~bpo60+1, and candidate is 1.2.0~rc3-1~bpo60+1, which will get installed on next `apt-get upgrade`.  Also there's some older version available from yet another repository.

**How to download Debian archive key?**

Debian archive key is published on [ftp-master](http://ftp-master.debian.org/keys.html).  You will need to import the key into your gpg keyring:

```
$ gpg --import archive-key-6.0.asc 
gpg: key 473041FA: public key "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: 3 marginal(s) needed, 1 complete(s) needed, PGP trust model
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   9  signed:  31  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 9u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:  31  signed:  38  trust: 25-, 0q, 0n, 1m, 5f, 0u
gpg: depth: 2  valid:  21  signed:  31  trust: 19-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 2f, 0u
gpg: depth: 3  valid:   3  signed:  12  trust: 2-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 1f, 0u
gpg: depth: 4  valid:   1  signed:   8  trust: 1-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 0u
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2013-09-22
```

Then you will have to check its signatures:

```
$ gpg --list-sig 473041FA
pub   4096R/473041FA 2010-08-27 [expires: 2018-03-05]
uid                  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sig 3        473041FA 2010-08-27  Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (6.0/squeeze) <ftpmaster@debian.org>
sig          7E7B8AC9 2010-08-27  Joerg Jaspert <joerg@debian.org>
sig     P    B12525C4 2010-08-27  [User ID not found]
sig          D0EC0723 2010-08-27  [User ID not found]
sig          8AEA8FEE 2010-08-27  [User ID not found]
sig          A3AE44A4 2010-08-28  [User ID not found]
sig          00D8CD16 2010-08-28  Alexander Reichle-Schmehl <alexander@reichle.schmehl.info>
sig          CD15A883 2010-08-28  [User ID not found]
sig          672C8B12 2010-08-28  [User ID not found]
sig 2        C4CF8EC3 2010-08-28  [User ID not found]
sig 2        D628A5CA 2010-08-28  [User ID not found]
```

And track the individual GPG keys to Debian developers either by tracking it manually, or f.e. checking at [PGP Key Statistics](http://pgp.cs.uu.nl/stats/7E7B8AC9.html) project.  And unless there's a chain from your PGP/GPG key to the Debian key archive, you will have to make a leap of faith at some point of time.

**How to download and verify individual packages by hand**

So the other approach is more complicated, because deb packages are not signed individually, but only the `Release` file is signed.  Thus you will need to download and verify the signature on `Release` and `Packages` files together with the individual package.

I will add an example that will be clearer.

Imagine you want to download Debian package for [Knot DNS](https://www.knot-dns.cz/) from [it's official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cz.nic-labs/+archive/knot-dns) for Ubuntu precise on amd64 architecture.

You will have to click through the directories and find these files:

```
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/cz.nic-labs/knot-dns/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/cz.nic-labs/knot-dns/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/cz.nic-labs/knot-dns/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/cz.nic-labs/knot-dns/ubuntu/pool/main/k/knot/knot_1.2.0~rc3-1~precise+1_amd64.deb
```

The next step would be to verify the signature on the `Release` file:

```
$ gpg --verify Release.gpg Release
gpg: Signature made Fri 01 Mar 2013 07:14:38 PM CET using RSA key ID F9C59A45
gpg: Good signature from "Launchpad Datové schránky"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 5246 3488 670E 69A0 9200  7C24 F233 1238 F9C5 9A45
```

Of course you'll need to verify the key in some other means (like the Debian/Ubuntu maintainers key, checking it from launchpad, etc, etc...)

When you have verified the correct signature on `Release` file you can go to next step – verifying the Packages file.

```
sha256sum Packages
c96a524398cf6e9db033c8299974fe324eba47cc8190efec6495c74e251330ad  Packages
$ grep c96a524398cf6e9db033c8299974fe324eba47cc8190efec6495c74e251330ad Release
 c96a524398cf6e9db033c8299974fe324eba47cc8190efec6495c74e251330ad             3379 main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

As you can see, the signature can be found in the signed `Release` file, thus we have verified the integrity of `Packages` file by computing and comparing its SHA-256 fingerprint.

The last step is similar.  You need to compute and compare the fingerprint of the individual package:

```
$ sha1sum knot_1.2.0~rc3-1~precise+1_amd64.deb 
8b34078e9bfef7aa818b2f926a28838b0ede9f43  knot_1.2.0~rc3-1~precise+1_amd64.deb
$ grep -A 13 "Package: knot$" Packages | grep "^SHA1: "
SHA1: 8b34078e9bfef7aa818b2f926a28838b0ede9f43
```

At this point we have securely chained the package to the signed `Release` file.  So if you believe the signature on the `Release` file, you can be sure that the package was downloaded intact.

You can read more in [Secure APT](http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) article at Debian Wiki.

Comment: Could you please explain why the `gpg` command should not need root priviledges? It is supposed to be an administrative tool.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez It is not an administrative tool; you can read more about GnuPG here: https://gnupg.org/