# Is there a way to pull source for a package for a specific release?

Tags: apt

Is there a way to pull source for a package (`apt-get source`) but specify the release? For example, I'd love to be able to just run `apt-get source --raring python-imaging`. I know I can manually pull from `packages.ubuntu.com`, is there a tool that can do this for me?

Comment: the release is usually specified in the url of the package source/repo not in the command

Comment: Is the tag rmadison relevant for this question?

Comment: I was thinking rmadison would be part of the solution, perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of.

Assuming you have that release in your `sources.list` you can do something like this.

```
apt-get source python-imaging/raring
```

Of course, if you are going to put other releases in your system `sources.list` you will also need to put appropriate pinning in place, or your regular use of `apt-get` will suffer. A better option then, in my opinion, is to use a separate apt environment, temporarily pointing to it using the `APT_CONFIG` environment variable.

The [link](http://blog.bogosity.se/2012/11/03/fully-using-apt-get-download/) below point to a blog post on how I put those pieces together for `apt-get` download. The exact same principle applies for `apt-get source`, just that you instead need the `deb-src` entries in your custom `sources.list`.

http://blog.bogosity.se/2012/11/03/fully-using-apt-get-download/

Comment: I think what I need to do is patch rmadison to pull source.